# Риск здоровью vs Риск для здоровья

Tags: словосочетания

В моей научной области многие специалисты употребляют словосочетание "риск здоровью". Это явно калькировано с английского health risk. Это словосочетание содержит даже название журнала, издаваемого в РФ и название института в Перми. "Оценка риска здоровью населения" устойчивое словосочетание, используемое многими авторами.
В попытке доказать некорректность подобной конструкции я перерыл всё, что смог найти самостоятельно, включая словари сочетаемости слов, но убедительно обосновать, почему считаю такую конструкцию недопустимой я не смог. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Моя аргументация больше интуитивна, чем научна:
Здоровью можно причинить вред (нанести ущерб), но нельзя причинить или нанести риск.